# XML formatting from HTTP response

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, parsing, httpresponse

I am using some asp.net/c# and some HP ILO scripts which I POST and then I get a repsonse (which should be XML)

Unfortunately the response if not correctly formatted XML so using an XML parser is impossible due to the errors.

Here is a sample output:

```
IP Address is: 10.3.3.1
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RIBCL VERSION="2.22">
    <RESPONSE
        STATUS="0x0000"
        MESSAGE='No error'
     />
    <INFORM>Scripting utility should be updated to the latest version.</INFORM>
</RIBCL>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RIBCL VERSION="2.22">
    <RESPONSE
        STATUS="0x0000"
        MESSAGE='No error'
     />
</RIBCL>
<GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>
    <FANS>
        <FAN>...
```

so the data I care for is all within `<GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>` which works fine with the XML parser if I remove the incorrect syntax.

My question is how to pull/format just the data I need? 
I know I could probably save the incorrect xml response to a text file, format it, then xml parse it but is there a nicer/quicker way of doing this?

Doing that for 100 runs in succession will take long too.

Comment: Is it impossible to fix the problem at its root? It looks like somebody forgot a debug message

Comment: Yes I've thought of that but the only to way do that is ask the HP ILO devleopers to do it for me which won't happen. Another way would be to parse the XML as text and mess around with string manipulation but that is too error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've shown above, the XML portions themselves are well-formed, but the text contains multiple XML declarations and multiple roots.  Are those the only issues or is there actual bad XML elsewhere?

If those are the only issues, something like this might work:

```
string declarationsRemoved = output.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>", "");

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root>" + declarationsRemoved + "</root>");

XmlNode healthData = doc.SelectSingleNode("/root/GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA");
```

Alternatively, you could extract just the part you need using a Regex:

```
string healthDataXml = Regex.Match(output, 
    "<GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>.*</GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>", RegexOptions.Singleline).ToString();
```

Comment: Yeah multiple roots is an issue (running multiple scripts which all give their own root) but you also have normal text such as `IP Address is: 10.3.3.1`at the start of the repsonse and also something similar at the end.

Comment: The Regex is also a good idea but it seems not to pick up the `<GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>` tags because they come back with escape characters from the response stirng such as `\t\r\n\t<GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH_DATA>`. How to account for that

Comment: The `IP Address is: 10.3.3.1` part should not be a problem for the first approach as long as you wrap it in begin and end tags as I demonstrated above.  The only case where that extra text would be an issue is if it contained < or &.

Comment: I think probably the reason the regex didn't work is that the portion you're trying to extract spans multiple lines and in that case you need to use the RegexOptions.Singleline option. I've modified my code above accordingly.

Comment: You were right. after the RegexOptions.Singleline it works just fine. Thanks again :)